# Twitter integration

Tags: lua, twitter

My computer game is powered using [Love2d](http://love2d.org) in Lua, there is dead space in the menu of my game and I'd like to fill it up with something. So I'll like to put a twitter feed there, how can I receive all the twitter posts created by AND mentioned from @stickydestroyer; how can I make it look good and code the actual thing.

I know I have to use some sort of cURL module, but how can I get the feed AND make it looking nicely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll probably want to use the [REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api) to recover a [user timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) and/or a [mentions timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline).

To make requests you'll probably want a [socket](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/) and [JSON](https://github.com/harningt/luajson) API for Lua. You find a specific example involving the use of both of those APIs to talk to a different REST API (not Twitter's) [here](http://www.kinvey.com/blog/98/resting-anywhere-using-kinvey8217s-api-with-the-lua-programming-language), which you can probably adapt to use for Twitter based on their documentation.

What you'll get from the Twitter endpoint is JSON data, which you can then format as appropriate to make it look nice within the context of your game.

Comment: Some pitfalls from having done similar things with the Facebook API: `luasocket.http` does not block, so you'll need to `love.thread`. LuaJSON is buggy with unicode characters, so you may have to fudge the results a bit.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't block?

Comment: It means the function will return to your code immediately but (in this case) the actual HTTP request may not be complete yet, because it's being carried out by another thread or something. By contrast a blocking call would involve waiting within the function until the request completed fully and the response was available to you.

Comment: Oops, I typoed! `luasocket.http` *does* block! (So you'll need a thread.) The explanation from Josh is correct though. Sorry!

Comment: Aha, so it "sleeps" until the value is returned.

Comment: You could put it that way, yes.

Comment: I knew the concept, didn't realise it was called "block"; thanks!